# Zip with exclusion pattern

Tags: gradle

I need to take an archive file and repacked it to another archive file with certain files excluded.
But this does not work?

```
task zipSrc(type:Zip){
    from (zipTree("${devDir}/classes_dex2jar.jar")) {
        exclude "*com/*"
    }
    destinationDir=file(devDir)
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Perhaps you want `*com/**`?

Comment: Actually I have it coded like this: exclude 'com/foo/foobar/**' but it is not excluded in the newly created archive

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps there is a spelling error or something.

Comment: It probably was a typo. I copy pasted the code posted in my previous comment and it worked.